# PineScript: How to translate priceline on y-axis by priceline? Keeps Flatlining ෴ -> _____

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How can I get the last price in Pine Script?

[image]

That number.

I need it as a float instead of series float.

Doing this:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="EURUSD")
inputEURUSD = input.symbol("EURUSD")
EURUSDprice = request.security(inputEURUSD, timeframe.period, close)
lastPriceEURUSD = EURUSDprice[0] 
EURUSDtoZero = EURUSDprice - 1.09107 // translate on y-axis manually
EURUSDminusLastPrice = EURUSDprice - lastPriceEURUSD // attempt to translate on y-axis automatically
plot(series=EURUSDprice, color=color.red, title="EURUSD", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(series=lastPriceEURUSD, color=color.green, title="EURUSD[0]", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(series=EURUSDtoZero, color=color.blue, title="EURUSD-1.09107", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(series=EURUSDminusLastPrice, color=color.white, title="EURUSD-EURUSD[0]", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false)
```

Gives you a flat line. As it should:
[image]
[image]
But if:

```
priceEURUSD[0]
```

gives you a series, than, how can I get that number as a float instead of series float, and use it to translate the priceline downwards by that many units on y-axis?

---

UPDATE:

I need it, basically, to represent varying degrees of movement in a single graph.
Take these boring lines, for example:

[image]

They're meaningless. But with a bit of manual translation on the y-axis, they start to take a meaningful shape:

[image]

So an automatic way to translate them by their last price, has to be found somewhere.

Even more so - the more converging you can get them, the more pronounced and meaningful they become.

---

ANSWER:

[image]

```
ta.tsi(USDEURprice, 10, 10)
```

Above graph shows, the upper lines, been translated manually and the bottom lines, been done with ta.tsi()

The resolution can be controlled with the "10, 10" (the smaller, the better resolution)

Comment: This is completely off-topic, but thanks for introducing me to ෴, which from a googling can serve as a "concluding remark" (e.g. for math proofs).

Comment: Why do you say, that translating a line with a scrip on y-axis is off topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: I meant my comment was off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your idea, You can use `ta.tsi` true strength index. It uses moving averages of the underlying momentum of a financial instrument.
[chart for true strength index indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyDk.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="EURUSD")

fast=9
slow=9

inputEURUSD = input.symbol("EURUSD")
price = request.security(inputEURUSD, timeframe.period, close)
EURUSDtoZero = price - 1.09107 // translate on y-axis manually
EURUSDminusLastPrice = price - price[close] // attempt to translate on y-axis automatically



EURUSDprice_tsi = ta.tsi(price, slow, fast)
lastPriceEURUSD_tsi = ta.tsi(price[close], slow, fast)
EURUSDtoZero_tsi = ta.tsi(EURUSDtoZero, slow, fast)
EURUSDminusLastPrice_tsi = ta.tsi(EURUSDminusLastPrice, slow, fast)

plot(EURUSDprice_tsi,color=color.red, title="EURUSD", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(lastPriceEURUSD_tsi, color=color.green, title="EURUSD[0]", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(EURUSDtoZero_tsi, color=color.blue, title="EURUSD-1.09107", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false) 
plot(EURUSDminusLastPrice_tsi,color=color.red, color=color.white, title="EURUSD-EURUSD[0]", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, trackprice=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

EURUSDprice is the number. [0] is not needed and adds nothing. You can use EURUSDprice in other calculations. Last price is [1] as in one bar ago...

Comment: So far I have understood, yes. But you see. In the graph. When I try to translate the priceline downwards on y-axis, automatically, by the EURUSDprice or EURUSDprice[0] - I get a flat line.

Comment: indicator(title="EURUSD", precision = 4) increasing the precision of the numbers you will see you do not get zero, except for the white line because you are subtracting a number from itself. EURUSDprice is equal to EURUSDprice [0].

Comment: Ok. Tried precision = 10. Great tip! But how does that help for translating a priceline downwards on y-axis?

Comment: you can add and subtract values as you wish? I think the question has been answered though. You have the number as a float and as long as you dont subtract it from itself it will not be zero

Comment: No. You don't understand. Not at all. I didn't want noise in the graph and my question. My goal is to make several price lines converge to zero, so that tradingview visualization engine would represent the past price differences in

Comment: a meaningful way, relative to one another, instead of themselves. For that I need to be able to translate each priceline on y-axis by its current price.

Comment: But all that is not, in essence, relevant to just the thing, that I can translate the line on y-axis by a number if I write it manually (1.09107), but the line flatlines, if I do it automatically. So how can I get that number as a float instead of a series float?

Comment: tradingview API? Scraping the webpage? I bet not. But idk